# c#--how to set a pic in html element in webBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control

```
<input type="file" name="media empty"  multiple=""  data-original-title="Add photos or video" data-delay="150">
```

**i wan to upload a pic to  a web page in web Browser but i really dont know how to do that with c#
what i mean is i wan to upload a picture to a web site just with c# that web site is loaded in my web Browser**

Comment: Please clarify your question with some more sentences.

Comment: what i mean is i wan to upload a picture to a web site just with c# that web site is loaded in my web Browser

Comment: Have you tried to do some research before asking the question here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as i understand you want to see your picture right after you upload it on your web page. Try this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Photo">Photo</label>
            <input type="file"
                   id="Photo"
                   name="Photo"
                   onchange="show(this)" />
        </div>

<img id="onLoad"
             src="#"
             alt="qwerty">

<script>
function show(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#onLoad')
                .attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i know this but i want to do that in c sharp